# How to configure camel jetty producer endpoint to use SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, jetty, akka, typesafe-stack

Camel jetty endpoint allows several SSL options, but only applicable to consumer (i.e. server side). See [Apache Camel Jetty](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html)

Is there a way to force the producer to use the certificate without writing a bunch of codes? The remote server requires client authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like coding is the only option. There are two choices that I've tried: configure SSL to (1) JettyComponent or (2) https4 component.

```
def configJetty = {
  println("Configuring Jetty component...")

  val ksp = new KeyStoreParameters()
  ksp.setResource(keyStore)
  ksp.setPassword(keyPassword)

  val kmp = new KeyManagersParameters()
  kmp.setKeyStore(ksp)
  kmp.setKeyPassword(keyPassword)

  val scp = new SSLContextParameters()
  scp.setKeyManagers(kmp)

  val jettyComponent = camelContext.getComponent("jetty").asInstanceOf[JettyHttpComponent]
  jettyComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp)
```

}

Or

```
def configHttps4 = {
  println("Configuring HTTPS4 component...")

  val ksp = new KeyStoreParameters()
  ksp.setResource(keyStore)
  ksp.setPassword(keyPassword)

  val tsp = new KeyStoreParameters()
  tsp.setResource(trustStore)
  tsp.setPassword(trustPassword)


  val kmp = new KeyManagersParameters()
  kmp.setKeyStore(ksp)
  kmp.setKeyPassword(keyPassword)

  val tmp = new TrustManagersParameters()
  tmp.setKeyStore(tsp)

  val scp = new SSLContextParameters()
  scp.setKeyManagers(kmp)
  scp.setTrustManagers(tmp)

  val httpComponent = camelContext.getComponent("https4").asInstanceOf[HttpComponent]
  httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp)
```

}

Then the endpoint URL can be:

```
https4://somewhere.com
```

or

```
jetty:https://somewhere.com
```

Note: with the above code, jetty component won't be able to speak clear HTTP anymore.